# Issue installing expo

Tags: node.js, macos, react-native, npm, expo

I've installed expo using

```
npm install expo-cli --global
```

but when I try to run expo init, it gives me

```
zsh: permission denied: expo
```

and if I use sudo expo init, it gives me

```
sudo: expo: command not found
```

When I use echo $PATH, it contains

```
/Users/alex/.node_modules_global/lib/node_modules
/Users/alex/.npm-global/bin
```

Could someone help me with this? I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.4

Comment: what happends if u type npx before the expo init? so npx expo init oder with sudo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it to work by adding

```
/Users/alex/.node_modules_global/bin
```

to my path in ~/.bash_profile